# T_{0} space with clopen base is totally disconnected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, separation-axioms

I have a problem trying to prove the following theorem.

If $X$ is a $T_{0}$ space with a base $C$ of clopen sets, then X is totally disconnected.

By definition, a space is totally disconnected if and only if $C(x) = {x} \quad \forall x \in X$. I try to prove it by contradiction, suposing that $\exists y \in C(x) ,  x \neq y $ and trying to use the  $T_{0}$ property for finding a contradiction, but I am stucked.

I haven't found any solution to the problem in the web, so I would aprecciate if somebody could help me.

Regards.

Comment: $T_0$ says we have a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ that doesn't contain $y$, or a neighbourhood $V$ of $y$ that doesn't contain $x$. Now find a $W \in C$ that contains one but nor the other.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I managed to solve it with the answer and the property that any open set contains an element from the base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If $x\ne y$, then either there is an open $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$, or there is an open $U$ such that $y\in U$ and $x\notin U$. Without loss of generality assume that there is an open $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$. Since $X$ has a clopen base, there is a clopen $B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$. Use $B$ to show that $y\notin C(x)$.

Comment: I made the proof, thanks. I used the property that for a given connected subspace  $C \subseteq X$ if $B \subseteq X$ is a clopen set such that $C \cap B \neq \emptyset$ then $C \subseteq B$

Comment: @Aldo: You’re welcome. Yes, that’s one way to do it.